# Syntax error IGNORE 1 ROWS and selecting columns when loading csv

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to upload a CSV file using the following syntax

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\file\\upload.csv' INTO TABLE customer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS

(@col1,@col2,@col3) SET 
account_number=@col1,
customer=@col2,
customer_id=@col3
;
```

It works without the **IGNORE 1 ROWS** line.

Which is the right syntax to include **IGNORE 1 ROWS** in this case?

Comment: `IGNORE 1 LINES`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using MariaDB and not MySQL. The syntax `IGNORE 1 ROWS` is only supported by MySQL.

The syntax supported by both MySQL and MariaDB is `IGNORE 1 LINES`